# Is the sentence correct? "During the meeting that ... , I had ..."?

Tags: grammaticality

> "During the meeting that Dr. Edward Smith coordinated last month, I had the chance to meet with you and hear the possible projects ..."

English is my second language, and I usually feel that my sentences sound weird and ambiguous, so I need your help.

Is the top sentence meaningful and grammatically correct?  Do you have any suggestion to improve it if necessary?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. **Proofreading questions ("Is this correct?", "Are there any mistakes?")** or critique requests are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified**. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question for the reason Rathony gives—but as an aside, I don't see anything wrong with the wording in your quotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote: "During the meeting that Dr. Edward Smith coordinated last month, I had the chance to meet with you and hear the possible projects ..." is grammatically correct but not quite idiomatic to a native American English speaker. You might want to say instead, "During the meeting that Dr. Edward Smith coordinated last month, I enjoyed having the opportunity to meet with you and to learn about the possible projects...."

Comment: Except that "enjoyed" is adding something MEhsan didn't say. Perhaps he didn't enjoy the experience!